# Two Custom authentication api laravel with JWT

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel project I've implemented users' authentication using JWT, socialite and dingo.
Now I have other users which are in another table other than users table -let's call it 'doctors'- and i want to authenticate them.
How to separate the sessions of the two tables even though the configuration for authentication is

```
//config/auth.php

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
 'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have to edit config/auth to

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'user' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'hospitalization' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'hospitalizations',
    ]
],
```

and use `Auth::guard('hospitalization')` when i need to separate

Comment: So the table name is hospitalization not doctors?

Comment: Excuse me please, but if application get a JWT token which is most of the time, how aplication know which guard to use?